# How do I get the div background to change when I mouse over a link - using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to be able change the position of a background image in a containing div when I mouse over a link within that div.

Here is the [page](http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/): It is the two blue play buttons mid right.

I had it working before but it is broken and I can't get it to work properly.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="h-video">
<p><a class="play-video" href="#flashArea3">Secondary headline goes here to say something you want. This needs to grab their attention.</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".h-video").hover(function() {
 $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'top center' });
    }, function() {
 $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'bottom center' });
});
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use javascript? You can do this in CSS alone, although IE6 won't support it on a `<div>` element.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yr4yH/1/

*CSS from example above:*

```
.h-video {
    width: 461px;
    height: 67px;
    background-image: url("http://www.theideapeople.com/projectpath/ideapeople-new/_images/btn_video-home.png");
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.h-video:hover {
    background-position: top center;
}​
```

If you need to support IE6, I'm sure you could rework your layout so `.h-video` is an `<a>` element instead of a `<div>`.

Comment: this turned out to be the most effective solution for this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave a separate answer for this solution, but I'd still say to [use CSS instead of javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907539/how-do-i-get-the-div-background-to-change-when-i-mouse-over-a-link-using-jquery/3907622#3907622).

Your code that assigns then handlers with `.hover()` is running before the elements are loaded. Otherwise your code is correct.

The code example below wraps your code with `$(function() { ... });` which is a shortcut for [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which ensures that the document is loaded before your code runs.

```
   // Wrap your code like this so it doesn't run until the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    $(".h-video").hover(function() {
     $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'top center' });
        }, function() {
     $(this).closest("div").css({ 'background-position': 'bottom center' });
    });
});
```

Also, [jQuery's `.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) isn't necessary here, but it doesn't hurt either. Might as well remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. You have the positions reversed: "center top" not "top center" and "center bottom" not "bottom center" ref: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp
2. Use addClass and RemoveClass. Don't set styles in-line. Use it just like the example on docs.jquery.com.
3. If you don't need the IE support use CSS declaration w/o javascript.